# jquery + see if div with ID & custom data attribute exists

Tags: jquery, html

[image]

I have the above situation and I need to be able to check if a div with id=profile and custom data attribute - say 'hobartcity77' exists.

I have been testing this code:

```
 if($('div#mainContainer div#'+urlType).find('[data-unique='+urlUnique+']').length > 0) {

 }
```

however it only matches the first div - it doesn't seem to search though the list.

how can I get this to search the list of div's to see if I have a match.

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `find()` in your code is redundant as your first selector selects the div and `find()` tries to find another div within selected div, try this:

```
if($('#mainContainer div[data-unique='+urlUnique+']').length > 0) {
```

*please note that IDs must be unique*

Comment: thankyou and very good point... strange I didn't see that... :) thx

Answer (score 1):

You can't use same `id` for multiple elements. change those `id` to `class` and then proceed.

```
if( $('div#mainContainer div[data-unique='+ urlUnique +']' ).length > 0 ) {

}
```